# htaccess regex - FilesMatch using the string of the last directory from url/after the last slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a code here that rewrite URLs, denies filenames that has extension, and allows specific files.

```
RewriteEngine On
# XAMPP /Brian
# Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Brian/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# XAMPP /Brian
#Exclude from redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/pass.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/dist/.*\.(css|js)$

RewriteRule .* index.php

<FilesMatch "[^/]*(?!.*\/)\..*$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(php|css|js|txt)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Examples:

```
http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass/ # CORRECT, slash added
http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt # CORRECT, no slash added, no error 403
http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txts -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txts # CORRECT, no slash added, error 403
http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt/pass2-> http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt/pass2/ # CORRECT, no slash added, no error 403
http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt/pass2.txt -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt/pass2.txt # CORRECT, no slash added, no error 403
```

My problem is this.

```
http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txts/pass2.txt -> http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txts/pass2.txt # NOT CORRECT, no slash added, error 403
```

I noticed that the *FilesMatch* only reads the string before the first slash which is the `pass.txts` and not the `pass2.txt`.

How can I make it read the last string after the last slash? Need help. Thanks!

**Updated:**

```
RewriteEngine On
# XAMPP /Brian
# Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Brian/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# XAMPP /Brian
#Exclude from redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/pass.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/dist/.*\.(css|js)$

RewriteRule .* index.php

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.[^/.]+$ - [F]

RewriteRule !\.(php|css|js|txt)$ - [NC,F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FilesMatch "[^/]*(?!.*\/)\..*$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Replace this block with a `mod_rewrite` rule as this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.[^/.]+$ - [F]
```

Then:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|css|js|txt)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Replace this block with a `mod_rewrite` rule as this:

```
RewriteRule !\.(php|css|js|txt)$ - [NC,F]
```

This will match `.txt` in `REQUEST_URI` instead of getting it from `REQUEST_FILENAME`. `F` is for returning `Forbidden` or `403` to clients.

---

Your full .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex inddex.php
RewriteEngine On
# XAMPP /Brian
# Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Brian/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$
RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(127\.0\.0\.1|::1)$
RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.[^/.]+$ - [F]

RewriteRule !\.(php|css|js|txt)$ - [NC,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/(index\.php|pass\.txt|/dist/.*\.(css|js))$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: It gives error 403 because of `<FilesMatch "[^/]*(?!.*/)\..*$">`. How should I deal with it?

Comment: yes it does work but the restriction to other files will be removed.

Comment: What is the full URL you tried? It will only allow `http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt`

Comment: No, `http://localhost:8080/Brian/pass.txt` is excluded from rewriting because of this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Brian/pass.txt$`.